# Intellij IDEA 12 with GWT: working directory is not equal to your web application root

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, intellij-idea

I create two GWT projects one is using maven the other not, in both situations it will give me below warning when launching my GWT app:

```
Warning: Your working directory, (C:\Users\XXX\.IntelliJIdea12\system\gwt\XXXX.xxxx\run\www) is not equal to your 
web application root (C:\Users\XXX\ws\myprj\myprj\target\myprj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
```

I specify the -war parameter in Dev Mode Parameters in Run/Debug Configuration, but seem no effect. and it has two -war options in the launching command line!

However the launching seem OK, I'm curious why this warning appear and how to fix.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to remove this warning is not use *-war* parameter in *Dev Mode Parameters* of Idea's *Run/Debug Configuration* for your buid configuration.

Explanation:

Idea honestly tells you the truth. It runs the server with the working directory defined to your_home_folder/.IntelliJIdea12/system/gwt/XXXX.xxxx/run/www

So if in the Run/Debug Configurations you have defined *Before launch: Make* it will build the project and copy everything required to this directory.

But you're defining -war for the *Dev Mode Parameters* that doesn't change the fact that idea builds the project to own directory because your parameter will be used only during run time. So Idea detects that fact late and warn you but Idea doesn't know that you're actually referring to the correct directory from your build results and it should work the same.  So that is why it works despite the Idea's warning.

I don't know why you have to use directory from the target so if this requirement is not strict and you can remove this *-war* parameter from your *Dev Mode parameters* it will still work because Idea makes and deploys everything you need to own working directory.